# i need to fetch records from one table where column value will be start with 'some value' and end with 'another some value'

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$nqry = mysql_query("select * FROM table_name where column_name BETWEEN 'AlertStopPressed' AND 'AlertStart'");
while($nftc = mysql_fetch_array($nqry)){
    echo $nftc['user_id']." - ".$nftc['alert_detail_id']." - ".$nftc['name']." - ".$nftc['alert_datetime']."<br>";
}
```

I have to group these value.
[please see the image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4rJj.png)

Comment: Use `groupBy` and `Limit`

Comment: Thanks for your support, but here i cannot use 'groupBy' because, if you see the image, i think you will understand and please give better solution. but finally i will have to groupBy

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Comment: ok, thanks your advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where columnname like 'startvalue%endvalue';
```

your query

```
$nqry = mysql_query("select * FROM table_name where column_name BETWEEN 'AlertStopPressed' AND 'AlertStart'") and columnname like 'startvalue%endvalue';
```

Comment: tnx for your instruction @sugumar 
according to your instruction i have put this query. but not working

select * FROM alert_detail where (name BETWEEN 'AlertStopPressed' AND 'AlertStart') and (name like '%AlertStopPressed%' and '%AlertStart%')